# C++: How to dynamically add a suffix to a line of text in a 'for' loop to create a previously declared variable

Tags: c++, for-loop

Does anyone know how one can add a variable value to a line of text in a for loop
in order to check for that variable?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    rendTarX = BUTTONCOLOR(i); //
    rendTarY = BUTTONCOLOR(i);
    writeUserInterfaceToBuffer(consoleBuffer, BUTTONCOLOR(i).chars, 
                               BUTTONCOLO(i)0.colors, BUTTONCOLOR(i).nWidth, 
                               BUTTONCOLOR(i).nHeight, rendTarX, rendTarY, 
                               userColor);
}
```

I have 16 buttons in total and want to write them to the screen buffer

Their names all start with 'BUTTONCOLOR' and end on a number between '0'
and '15'.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: *"Their names all start with 'BUTTONCOLOR' and end on a number between '0' and '15'."* Why not just use an array instead?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected results ? It is unclear if you are asking how to use an array or how to concatenate a name and an index.

Comment: Hi. I tried that a few times but ran into the problem that the loop wouldn't use the value associated to 'BUTTONCOLORSX00'. It tried to cram the chars into rendTarX which is an int.

Comment: @Clonk I would expect a loop that changes the name of the variable currently used by adding the value of 'i' to it. So in the first iteration it would do:                           rendTarX = BUTTONCOLOR0;                                                                                         In the next iteration it would do:                                                                                          rendTarX = BUTTONCOLOR1;                                                                                                         And so on.

Comment: You can't do that. The variable names are only there for the programmer, they don't make it into the program's executable. Thus the program can't dynamically puzzle together variable names to find the correct variable, it looks like you need to use an array instead.

Comment: I will try to make an array of pointers again then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is probably to use an array and access it by index :

```
std::array<int, 16> BUTTONCOLORS = {BUTTONCOLORSX00, BUTTONCOLORSX01, ..., BUTTONCOLORSX15};
```

`BUTTONCOLORS[i]` will give you the variable you want.

If you REALLY want to concatenate variable then you can use a macro :

```
#define _BUTTONCOLORS(n) BUTTONCOLORSX##n
#define BUTTONCOLORS(n) _BUTTONCOLORS(n)
```

`BUTTONCOLORS(1)` will be resolved in preprocessor as `BUTTONCOLORSX1` and 
  `BUTTONCOLORS(2)` will be resolved in preprocessor as  `BUTTONCOLORSX2`.

You will need a compile time loop for the macros to be resolved so you cannot use a for loop. You **have** to do the loop in a macro too (because everything is resolved in preprocessor stage).

That being said, I **strongly recommend** using an array and not a macro because it is **safer** and more **readable**. Using macros is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring 16 variables with similar names, declare *one* array.

```
std::array<Color, 16> ButtonColors;
```

If you have initial values, provide them all in one go

```
std::array<Color, 16> ButtonColors = { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... }; // or whatever initialises Colors
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did just that for the 4-bit color values. Gonna rewrite the whole program tomorrow in an object-oriented style.